# GWT Java Obfuscation

Tags: java, gwt

I am developing GWT API. I am trying to find a way for obfuscation to my java code(API). But, GWT works only with source code. But I dont want my algorithms does not understand from developers who use my GWT API. Is there any way to obfuscate my java codes. Another isue is licencing. Is there any way, developing client licence for GWT.

Comment: Are you trying to obfuscate the generated Javascript?  Or what?

Comment: GWT client code is obfuscated to some extend already. It's alomost impossible to understand your logic from the generated Javascript. May be you can give it a try by doing reverse engineering generated Javascript.

Answer (score 6):

The GWT Compiler only works on source code because we need the extra on information that is inside java files compared to class files.

So if you want to develop an API for GWT you can only do this by shipping open code to your customers.